# Counting keys in a JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

The problem is not the counting itself; it's actually setting the key->value pair what I can't set. Here's the code:

```
<?php
$jsonPacks = '{
    "pack": [
        {
            "container": 50,
            "layout": [
                {
                    "id": 4054,
                    "stacksize": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "container": 50,
            "layout": [
                {
                    "id": 4054,
                    "stacksize": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "container": 50,
            "layout": [
                {
                    "id": 4054,
                    "stacksize": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "container": 50,
            "layout": [
                {
                    "id": 4054,
                    "stacksize": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "container": 50,
            "layout": [
                {
                    "id": 4054,
                    "stacksize": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "container": 50,
            "layout": [
                {
                    "id": 4054,
                    "stacksize": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 9713,
                    "stacksize": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 9713,
                    "stacksize": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 9713,
                    "stacksize": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 9713,
                    "stacksize": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 81519,
                    "stacksize": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 81519,
                    "stacksize": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 81519,
                    "stacksize": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 81519,
                    "stacksize": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 81519,
                    "stacksize": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 81519,
                    "stacksize": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}';
function _countItemsByContainer($containerId, $arrayPack) {
    $obj = [];
    for ($j = 0;$j < count($arrayPack['pack']);$j++) {
        if ($j == $containerId) {
            $totalLayouts = count($arrayPack['pack'][$j]['layout']);
            echo 'LAYOUT: ' . $totalLayouts . '<br>';
            for ($k = 0;$k < $totalLayouts;$k++)            {
                if ($obj[$arrayPack['pack'][$j]['layout'][$k]['id']])                {
                    $obj[$arrayPack['pack'][$j]['layout'][$k]['id']]++;
                } else {
                    $obj[$arrayPack['pack'][$j]['layout'][$k]['id']] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $obj;
}
$arrayPack = json_decode($jsonPacks, true);
$totalCartonizations = count($arrayPack['pack']);
$countItemsByContainer = [];
for ($k = 0;$k < $totalCartonizations;$k++){
    $countItemsByContainer[] = _countItemsByContainer($k, $arrayPack);
}
print_r(json_encode($countItemsByContainer));
?>
```

This is what the code returns:

```
[
    {
        "4054": 1
    },
    {
        "4054": 1
    },
    {
        "4054": 1
    },
    {
        "4054": 1
    },
    {
        "4054": 1
    },
    {
        "4054": 1,
        "9713": 4,
        "81519": 6
    }
]
```

Which is correct. The counter is reporting how many of what id are in each of the 6 packs.

What I need is a JSON with the following structure:

```
{
    "pack": [
        {
            "item": [
                {
                    "id": 4054,
                    "total": 1
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "item": [
                {
                    "id": 4054,
                    "total": 1
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "item": [
                {
                    "id": 4054,
                    "total": 1
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "item": [
                {
                    "id": 4054,
                    "total": 1
                },
            ]
        },      
        {
            "item": [
                {
                    "id": 4054,
                    "total": 1
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "item": [
                {
                    "id": 4054,
                    "total": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 9713,
                    "total": 4
                },
                {
                    "id": 81519,
                    "total": 6
                },              
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

Or something like that.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't down vote a question if you can't answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer:

```
function _countItemsByContainer($containerId, $arrayPacks) {
    for ($j = 0;$j < count($arrayPacks['pack']);$j++) {
        if ($j == $containerId) {
            $allItems = [];
            for ($k = 0; $k < count($arrayPacks['pack'][$j]['layout']); $k++) {
                if (in_array($arrayPacks['pack'][$j]['layout'][$k]['id'], $allItems)) {
                    $key = array_search($arrayPacks['pack'][$j]['layout'][$k]['id'], array_column($obj['item'], 'id'));
                    $obj['item'][$key]['total']++;
                } else {
                    $obj['item'][] = ['id' => $arrayPacks['pack'][$j]['layout'][$k]['id'], 'total' => 1];
                    $allItems[] = $arrayPacks['pack'][$j]['layout'][$k]['id'];
                }                
            }
        }
    }
    return $obj;
}
$arrayPacks = json_decode($jsonPacks, true);
$totalPacks = count($arrayPacks['pack']);
$countItemsByContainer = [];
for ($k = 0; $k < $totalPacks; $k++){
    $countItemsByContainer['pack'][] = _countItemsByContainer($k, $arrayPacks);
}
echo '<pre>';
echo json_encode($countItemsByContainer, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo '</pre>';
```